# Android Firebase: invalid case sensitive name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a Track type object into the firebase DB which has an ArrayList of Checkpoint type objects.

```
ssDB.child("tracks").child(trackKey).setValue(newTrack)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
03-25 09:35:38.293 9189-9189/com.illbirdstudios.illbird.streetsend E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.illbirdstudios.illbird.streetsend, PID: 9189
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found setter with invalid case-sensitive name: setCheckpoints
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.<init>(Unknown Source:403)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzf(Unknown Source:12)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source:756)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source:0)
     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
     at com.illbirdstudios.illbird.streetsend.CreateTrackActivity2$1$1.onDataChange(CreateTrackActivity2.java:174)
     at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source:7)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source:13)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:65)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
```

Here is my Track Class

```
public class Track {

    private String trackOwner;
    private String trackName;

    public final static String POINTTOPOINT = "POINTTOPOINT";
    public final static String CIRCUIT = "CIRCUIT";

    private String trackType;
    private ArrayList<Checkpoint> checkpoints;

    public Track(String trackOwner, String trackName, String trackType){

        this.trackOwner = trackOwner;
        this.trackName = trackName;
        this.trackType = trackType;
        checkpoints = new ArrayList<Checkpoint>();

    }

    public Track(){

    }

    public String getTrackOwner(){
        return this.trackOwner;
    }

    public String getTrackName(){
        return this.trackName;
    }

    public String getTrackType(){
        return this.trackType;
    }

    public void setCheckpoints(ArrayList<Checkpoint> checkpoints){
        this.checkpoints = checkpoints;
    }

    public void addCheckPoint(Checkpoint checkpoint){
        checkpoints.add(checkpoint);
    }

    public ArrayList<Checkpoint> getCheckPoints(){
        return this.checkpoints;
    }
}
```

When I try adding each of the Track items seperatly through child calls to the database, it works:

```
Log.d("Saving Track", "Track Name");
ssDB.child("tracks").child(trackKey).child("trackName").setValue(newTrack.getTrackName());
Log.d("Saving Track", "Track Owner");
ssDB.child("tracks").child(trackKey).child("trackOwner").setValue(newTrack.getTrackOwner());
Log.d("Saving Track", "Track Type");
ssDB.child("tracks").child(trackKey).child("trackType").setValue(newTrack.getTrackType());
Log.d("Saving Track", "Track Checkpoints");
ssDB.child("tracks").child(trackKey).child("checkpoints").setValue(newTrack.getCheckPoints());
```

But not when I set the value as the object itself.

```
ssDB.child("tracks").child(trackKey).setValue(newTrack)
```

Comment: At least the getter vs the setter and the variable name do not match. One is `CheckPoints`, the others are `Checkpoints`.

Comment: I thought firebase only saved strings (because it uses JSON to store data).  You can't just set some arbitrary object like as a value can you?

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because of the following field:

```
private ArrayList<Checkpoint> checkpoints;
```

The correct getter and setter should be:

```
public ArrayList<Checkpoint> getCheckpoints() {
    return checkpoints;
}

public void setCheckpoints(ArrayList<Checkpoint> checkpoints) {
    this.checkpoints = checkpoints;
}
```

Your getter should be `getCheckpoints()` and not `getCheckPoints()` as it is in your code. See lower case `p` vs. capital letter `P`.

Comment: Ahh I see now, but I don't understand why It would matter if the P is uppercase? Like how does the compiler know which character needs to be uppercase?

Comment: When the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects coming from the database, is looking for fields that follow the principles of the JavaBeans and are named accordingly to [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). So the corresponding getter for a field like `checkpoints` is `getCheckpoints()` and not `getCheckPoints()`.If you whould have used a field that was named `checkPoints`, only in this case a getter like `getCheckPoints()` would worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your setters and getters should follow the principles of the Java Beans. At the moment your getter and setter do not match.

Moreover, consider not to use ArrayList for storing lists of data but Maps. In Firebase documentation, [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html?m=1), you find some best practices for storing lists.